# DataBinding in to object in List

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datasource

I have faced a problem, i have a List of objects, lets say Person:

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _name;
    private string _surname;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetField(ref _name, value, "name"); }

    }
    public string surname
    {
        get { return _surname; }
        set { SetField(ref _surname, value, "surname"); }

    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,167,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="585,167,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=surname}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="721,355,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

On page init i do this:

```
List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Person a = new Person();
        a.name = "First";
        a.surname = "FirstSurname";
        Persons.Add(a);
        Person b = new Person();
        b.name = "Second";
        b.surname = "SecondSurname";
        Persons.Add(b);
        this.DataContext = Persons[0];
    }
```

An i dont want to change the property, but change the whole object:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Person a = new Person();
        a.name = "Test";
        a.surname = "Test";
        Persons[0] = a;
    }
```

How can i make my TextBlocks to reget the data automatically? Not doing this.DataContext = Persons[0]; again

Comment: Why do you have a `List<Person>` when you only want to bind to the first element? Why not have a `CurrentPerson` property (with change notification) in `MainPage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Text** property in your **TextBlock**, try setting **UpdateSourceTrigger** to *PropertyChanged*:

```
Text="{Binding Path=name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Error 1 Unknown member 'UpdateSourceTrigger' on element 'Binding' c:\users\afomenko\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\App5\App5\MainPage.xaml 12 88 App5

Comment: But it wouldn't help anyway, because i'm not changing the property, i'm changing the whole object

Comment: Are you wrapping the two TextBlocks and Button around a DataTemplate or something? I am assuming the count of `Persons` in your list will change dynamically. If you have a DataTemplate with the TextBlocks and Button , you can set its **ItemsSource** to the list and set its **UpdateSourceTrigger** to **PropertyChanged**.